# How to add persistent IPv6 address in Vista/Windows7?

Tags: winapi, ip-address, ipv6

I want to add a persistent IPv6 address using just API calls or with Registry edits. I have currently implemented a code which uses [`CreateUnicastIpAddressEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to add the IPv6 address successfully, but the IP address is destroyed when the adapter is reset or machine rebooted (as mentioned in MSDN docs).

With IPv4, it was easy to do. Just use `AddIPAddress` API combined with registry entries to get the desired result.

I have tried to find any entry in the Windows Registry which is being used to save the IPv6 address without any success. The MSDN docs suggests to use `netsh.exe` to do the task, but then I am quite sure `netsh.exe` is doing some API call or Registry entry to achieve this task (which is not documented by Microsoft anywhere).

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Nicely asked question - looks like you put quite a bit of research into it.

Comment: @awoodland, ya man, done lot of research on it. This is the reason I guess IPv6 is still not picking up. No proper documentation available yet for serious stuff.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting those parameters like `store=persistent`?

Comment: I just tried to see what netsh.exe is doing in the background, using Sysinternal Process Monitor, only to find its doing a registry entry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi\{eb004a01-9b1a-11d4-9123-0050047759bc}\10

Its a REG_BINARY entry with some binary data of which I am not sure. Will check it with more experiments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after some reverse engineering of **netsh.exe** and detailed analysis I think there is sufficient info to create a persistent ipv6 address.

The ipv6 address (UNICAST) is stored in following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi\{eb004a01-9b1a-11d4-9123-0050047759bc}\10
```

For every ipv6 address to be added, create a REG_BINARY value such that the name of the value contains [NET_LUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) concatenated with the ipv6 address in full. Like for example, if the ipv6 address is 2001::1, the name of the value will be **000000090000060020010000000000000000000000000001**, where the first 16 characters is the NET_LUID of the network adapter and the rest the ipv6 address in full.

This registry value data is made of a 48 byte long structure given below:

```
typedef struct _UNKNOWN {
  ULONG            ValidLifetime;
  ULONG            PreferredLifetime;
  NL_PREFIX_ORIGIN PrefixOrigin;
  NL_SUFFIX_ORIGIN SuffixOrigin;
  UINT8            OnLinkPrefixLength;
  BOOLEAN          SkipAsSource;
  UCHAR            Unknown[28];
} UNKNOWN;
```

The last 28 bytes of this structure is unknown and must be initialized to 0xFF.

Refer to [MIB_UNICASTIPADDRESS_ROW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559308%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure info in msdn for more info on the UNKNOWN structure members.

While doing this, I also figured out that ipv6 ANYCAST addresses are stored similarly in registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi\{eb004a01-9b1a-11d4-9123-0050047759bc}\8`\
```

Comment: FWIW, it appears that LUID-to-GUID mappings can be constructed from information in `...\{eb004a11-9b1a-11d4-9123-0050047759bc}\10`, where the key name is the LUID, and the GUID is encoded at offset `0x410`. I'm not (yet) sure what the struct is called, but it also includes the FriendlyName and MAC address, plus other things. I know of `ConvertInterfaceIndexToLuid`, but that's not really a feasible option for me (cross-compiling from golang).